# ValueTask for synchronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, valuetask

I am implementing a simple lookup service using concurrent dictionary to store data.
Since most of the methods using this service will be async I am considering exposing the lookup functions with `ValueTask<TResult>`.

Pseudocode:

```
public ValueTask<string> GetResultAsync(string key)
{
 return ValueTask.FromResult(_dictionary.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == key).Value
}
```

Does this approach make sense and is there any caveats ?

Comment: It makes no sense, async methods call easily call sync methods. If you expose your methods as async you must really intend it, if IO, networking ot something external is envolved.

Comment: What about this method ever behaves in an asyncronous way? Are you considering providing some overriden implementation that uses some cache that is accessed async?

Comment: @CaiusJard I doubt that there will be any real async code involved, as you see in the example the only code that will run will be sync and it will just do a lookup or dictionary modification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since most of the methods using this service will be async, I am considering exposing the lookup functions with `ValueTask`.

This is not a valid reason for exposing a fake-asynchronous wrapper of a synchronous operation. Doing so you are adding needless overhead, and you are communicating wrong/misleading semantics to the consumers of your service. In fact the only valid reason that I am aware of to do so, is if you are building a base class and you expect that the derived classes will override this method and provide real asynchronous implementations.

Comment: I guess both of the points you mention is valid and fully understood, thanks a lot for your input!